# How to hide some text in string using CSS

Tags: html, css

Please find updated code

```html
<html>
<title>css</title>
<head>
<style>
#st {
z-index: -114;
margin-right: -80px;     
}
</style>
</head>
State Code : <span><span id="st"></span>Maharashtra - MH</span>
</html>
```

I got below output but i need clear overlapped text

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7NuQ.png)

Comment: This is not possible with css.

Comment: "Maharashtra" => It is a dynamic text or static text

Comment: This is dynamic text

Comment: Wrap the text you wants to hide in a `span`. Then you can hide it using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

the only way to approach this is using css display: none or visibility: hidden property , either one would work, i would advice display none. this is the only way CSS and HTML can hide data.

```html
<span>State Code: <span id="st"><span style="display: none">Maharashtra - </span>MH</span></span>
```

Comment: Maharashtra - MH comes from db this is a dynamic code

Comment: sorry buy css cant work that, try JavaScript or php it is very much more easier using both.

Answer (score 0):

## Update 2

Layout has significantly changed...see 2nd updated demo.

Since OP has dynamically generated text, JavaScript is needed realistically. And probably the actual text will be more than one on the page.

- This demo gathers all `<span>` nested within a `<span>` (could've used `#id` but realistically, it should be a `.class`). This NodeList is converted into an array.
- This array is then [**`map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)'ped on each iteration a regex is matched vs. the `<span>`s text.
- A [**`replace()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)'ment of the unwanted portion of text is overwritten and the last 2 letters remain.

### Demo

```js
var tgt = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span'));

tgt.map(function(s, idx) {

  var str = s.textContent;

  var rgx = /(State Code:).*?- (\w\w)/g;

  var rep = `$1 $2`;

  var res = str.replace(rgx, rep);

  s.textContent = res;
});
```

```html
<span>State Code: <span class="st"></span>California - CA</span><br>
<span>State Code: <span class="st"></span>New York - NY</span><br>
<span>State Code: <span class="st"></span>Oregon - OR</span><br>
<span>State Code: <span class="st"></span>Mississippi - MS</span><br>
```

Comment: what does it hide?

Comment: The `font-size:0` hides it. Yet it does exist.

Comment: Maharashtra - MH comes from db this is a dynamic code

Comment: @Shreya Then don't expect miracles from CSS. Rewrite your question to ask for JavaScript but emphasize that solution should be light on JavaScript if you are not confident with it.

Comment: I am using place holder in smarty

Answer (score 0):

You Can't do this by using CSS only here is the javascript solution for u

```js
$("#st").html(function(){
  var text= $(this).text().trim().split(" ");
  var first = text.shift();
  return (text.length > 0 ? "<span class='hide'>"+ first + "</span> " : first) + text.join(" ");
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>State Code: <span id="st">Maharashtra - MH</span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

see this is HTML version but it is working fine.

```
<span id="span_Id">Maharashtra - MH</span>

<script>
function getSecondPart(str) {
    return str.split('-')[1];
}
var span_Text = document.getElementById("span_Id").innerText;
var html = getSecondPart(span_Text);
document.getElementById("span_Id").innerHTML = html;

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use PHP... try it below..

```
$string = explode("-","Maharashtra - MH");

<span>State Code: <span id="st"><span style="display:none;"><?php echo $sting[0]."-"; ?></span><?php echo $string[1]; ?></span></span>
```